# Click on many elements not working: selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to get selenium to click elements in a for loop but I get that the element is not clickable and other element would receive the click. The code works if I make it only select one element instead of several and then click. Why does it not work in a for loop and what can I do to fix it?

This is the code:

```
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "thumbImage.loaded")))
    
for e in elem:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait
    e.click()
```

Comment: Are all those elements presented inside the visible screen area or you need to scroll to them?

Comment: @Prophet some are there but for others I have to scroll down

Comment: OK, let me know if cruispandey's solution didn't work and you still need assistance

Comment: @Prophet Thank you, it hasn't worked. If you have any ideas, I'd like to try them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **ActionsChain** in a loop like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "thumbImage.loaded")))
for e in elem:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(e).click().perform()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: make sure to launch browser in full screen

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I get this error now: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. I also forgot to mention that to get all the elements I need to scroll down a lot, maybe that affects it?

Comment: once you click on the first element, it will redirect you to some URL.. once you have moved away all the remaining item in list becomes stale. So once you are back to the original back (by any mean ) try to store them again and then click on the next element.

Comment: okay, I don't get the error anymore if I add another action I need to happen. I want this: e_title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'titleOfElement))). However, it returns selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException, do you know why that might be? I basically need to store the element's titles.

Comment: I could fix it but it just seems to iterate over the same first element instead of all of the elements.